# entity framework working

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would generate entity framework model of my whole database or do it scenario based with 2-5 tables entity model generation? What is the best thing to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate only the tables needed by the application. Then write wrappers around it based on scenario.